# IS it possible to save a Image to Remote computer folder using windows service?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I have an byte array of image in my local computer, using windows service i want to 
convert it as a image and save it in a server folder I know the Ip address of the server
As of now I have tried something like this

```
byte[] photo = publicData.Photography;                                           
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo, 0, photo.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Write(photo, 0, photo.Length);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);// this line giving exception parameter not valid
image.Save(172.16.16.32/E/xyz);
```

Comment: What is _"a server folder"_? Through which protocol do you want to save the image, FTP, HTTP, SMB, WebDAV? What is the result of your current code? The line you highlighted (`Image.FromStream`) indicates that the problem already occurs even before you try to save the image.

Comment: I have a folder in my server that is completely shared and the server IP Address is "172.16.16.32" in this server E drive xyz folder am trying to save

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the bytes, why bother with the streams and image obejcts?

```
byte[] photo = publicData.Photography;                                           
var path = @"\\172.16.16.32\E\xyz\file.jpg";

File.WriteAllBytes(path, photo);
```

Comment: am getting The network name cannot be found. as exception

Comment: @KeerthiKumar Well, then the network name could not be found. Can you access \\172.16.16.32\E\xyz\ in another tool like Windows Explorer?

Answer (score -2):

Please try this

var path = @"\172.16.16.32\E$\xyz\file.jpg";